# My li scope not remove in angular js Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hi Please Help me i m new in angular js

i just create a function. 
i m repeat the content .
i create a function who is add next tab section and remove this section.
i create a same function to another tab add prev tab section and remove this section .

But i thing only data copy this function not remove data and not show .

Please Help me

My code is this

**HTML Code is**

```
<body ng-app="taskPanel">
   <div class="" ng-controller="TasksController">
  <tabset panel-tabs="true" panel-class="panel-inverse">
       <tab>
                         <tab>
                            <tab-heading> <span class="hidden-xs">ACTIVE</span> <span class="badge badge-primary">{{tasksComplete.length}}</span></tab-heading>
                            <div class="tasklist">
                                <ol class="panel-tasks">
                                    <li ng-repeat="item in tasksComplete">
                                        <a href="#" class="preview-question">
                                            <i class="fa fa-eye">eye</i>
                                        </a>
                                        <label>
                                            <span class="task-description">{{item.title}}</span>
                                             <span class="label label-{{item.color || 'primary'}}" ng-show="item.label">{{item.label}}</span> 
                                             <div class="more-icn">
                                                <div class="pull-left">
                                                   <button  class="active-check" ng-click="pushActive(this, item)">Push to InActive Tab</button>
                                                </div>

                                             </div>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>
                         </tab>
                         <tab>
                            <tab-heading> <span class="hidden-xs">InACTIVE</span> <span class="badge badge-primary">{{tasksComplete.length}}</span></tab-heading>
                            <div class="tasklist">
                                <ol class="panel-tasks">
                                    <li ng-repeat="item in tasksInComplete">
                                        <a href="#" class="preview-question">
                                            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <label>
                                            <span class="task-description">{{item.title}}</span>
                                             <span class="label label-{{item.color || 'primary'}}" ng-show="item.label">{{item.label}}</span> 
                                             <div class="more-icn">
                                                <div class="pull-left">
                                                   <button  class="active-check" ng-click="pushInActive(this, item)">Push To Active Tab</button>
                                                </div>

                                             </div>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>
                         </tab>

   </tabset>

   </div>
  </body>
```

**ANgular Js code is**

// Code goes here

```
var appan = angular.module('taskPanel', []);
appan.controller('TasksController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.tasksComplete = [
      { title: "I m first" },
      { title: "I m Second" },
      { title: "I m thrid" }
    ];


    $scope.tasksInComplete = [
      {title: "i m incompletred 1"},
      {title: "i m incompletred 2"},
      {title: "i m incompletred 3"}
      ];


      $scope.remove = function(scope){
        scope.remove();
      };


      $scope.pushActive = function(scope, item){
        $scope.tasksInComplete.push(item);
        scope.remove();
      };

      $scope.pushInActive = function(scope, item){
        $scope.tasksComplete.push(item);
        scope.remove();
      };

}]);
```

and **[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/V3wNwL3F4gJfB1ldSMhT?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, use $index for remove elements in array

```
  $scope.pushActive = function(index, item){
    $scope.tasksComplete.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.tasksInComplete.push(item);

  };

  $scope.pushInActive = function(index, item){
    $scope.tasksInComplete.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.tasksComplete.push(item);

  };
```

plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/fp3gcf9PlBi9XnpNYFZQ?p=preview

Comment: HI @Kaken can i delay to this function i want to i click to in tab some take time around 3 second than move to next tab in motion

Comment: Hi @RohitAzad try use $timeout service. like http://plnkr.co/edit/aB1XNuaAqe52iSAjRLXl?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

you can use such approatch:

Controller:

```
 $scope.tasksComplete = [
   { title: "I m first"},
   { title: "I m Second"},
   { title: "I m thrid"}
 ];

 $scope.pushActive = function(item) {
   $scope.tasksComplete.splice(item,1);
 };
```

veiw

```
ng-click="pushActive($index)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code and you can see it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/11Gkjs?p=preview).

The wording was messing me up. Once I change the View wording to match the controller wording, it was good.

```
var appan = angular.module('taskPanel', []);
appan.controller('TasksController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.tasksInActive = [
    { title: "I m first" },
    { title: "I m Second" },
    { title: "I m thrid" }
  ];

  $scope.tasksActive = [
    {title: "i m incompletred 1"},
    {title: "i m incompletred 2"},
    {title: "i m incompletred 3"}
  ];

  $scope.pushActive = function(scope, item){
    $scope.tasksInActive = removeItemFromList(item, $scope.tasksInActive);
    $scope.tasksActive.push(item);
  };

  $scope.pushInActive = function(scope, item){
    $scope.tasksActive = removeItemFromList(item, $scope.tasksActive);
    $scope.tasksInActive.push(item);
  };

  function removeItemFromList(item, list){
    return list.filter(function(i){
      return i != item;  
    });
  }
}]);
```

Comment: I think it's more efficient not use the function removeItemFromList
With $ index and splice methods is all that is needed